# How to 'follow' foreign keys in a SQL client

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently using Sequel Pro to view my database. I find much of my time spent on 'following' foreign keys. For example, if an entry in table A links to table B, I find myself writing down the id number, then clicking the other table, scrolling down to find that id, etc. It becomes quite tedious.

Is there a way in Sequel Pro or in another SQL client to link to the FK (e.g., double click the FK and it takes you to that entry)?

Comment: if you r using `phpmyadmin`, then there is a way i can tell you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can benefit from the foreign key lookup editor for easy editing of fields referencing other tables in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

[image]